# What does % do in Linux shell strings?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

In Linux shell, what does % do, as in:

```
for file in *.png.jpg; do
  mv "$file" "${file%.png.jpg}.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Every time I look this up, I usually find the right section of the bash man page by searching for `%%` or `##`, since that's memorable and rare enough to find the right section quickly.  `man bash` `/##`

Comment: @PeterCordes I always rememer this by "It's 5%, so % is at the end and thus cuts from the end. And it's #5, so # is at the start and cuts from the start."
But sometimes I even mix up this one…

Comment: @glglgl:  On a typical USA keyboard, `#` is immediately to the left of `$`, and `%` is immediately to the right.  No mnemonic needed --- just look down.  (That's probably at least part of why those symbols were chosen.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Not everyone worldwide has a typical USA keyboard. But indeed, on a German keyboard, % is right of $ as well, that could be a start for memoizing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When `%` is used in pattern `${variable%substring}` it will return content of `variable` with the shortest occurance of `substring` deleted from back of `variable`.

This function supports wildcard patterns - that's why it accepts star (asterisk) as a substite for zero or more characters.

It should be mentioned that this is Bash specific - other linux shells don't neccessarily contain this function.

If you want to learn more about string manipulation in Bash, i highly suggest reading [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) page. Among other handy functions it - for example - explains what does `%%` do :)

Edit: I forgot to mention that when it's used in pattern `$((variable%number))` or `$((variable1%$variable2))` the `%` character will function as modulo operator. DavidPostill has more specific documentation links in his answer.

When `%` is used in different context, it should be recognized as regular character only.

Comment: The operator supports *wildcard patterns*, not regular expressions.

Comment: Like gardenhead mentioned - it supports glob patterns, not regular expressions. In regular expression a star means zero or more of the previous character.

Comment: The guide you've linked to is very much *not* recommended [by most Unix & Linux stack exchange users](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/305358/135943).  I recommend the [Wooledge Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) instead.

Comment: The prefix and suffix removing operators are [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), so they should be usable in any `sh`-compatible shell, not only Bash. (though perhaps not in `csh` and the like).

Comment: Another context in which `%` is used is in format specifiers for `printf`.

Answer (score 9):

> [Bash Reference Manual: Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
>
> `${parameter%word}`
> `${parameter%%word}`
>
> The *word* is expanded to produce a
>   pattern just as in filename expansion. If the pattern matches a
>   trailing portion of the expanded value of *parameter*, then the result
>   of the expansion is the value of *parameter* with the shortest matching
>   pattern (the `‘%’` case) or the longest matching pattern (the `‘%%’` case)
>   deleted. If *parameter* is `‘@’` or `‘*’,` the pattern removal operation is
>   applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list. If *parameter* is an array variable subscripted with `‘@’`
>   or `‘*’,` the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the
>   array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: N.B. some parameter expansions including % are posix features that many shells support.

Answer (score 7):

By experimenting, I find that a match after % is discarded, when the string is enclosed in curly brackets (braces).

To illustrate:

```
touch abcd         # Create file abcd

for file in ab*; do
 echo $file        # echoes the filename
 echo $file%       # echoes the filename plus "%"
 echo ${file%}     # echoes the filename
 echo "${file%}"   # echoes the filename
 echo
 echo "${file%c*}" # Discard anything after % matching c*
 echo "${file%*}"  # * is not greedy
 echo ${file%c*}   # Without quotes works too
 echo "${file%c}"  # No match after %, no effect
 echo $file%c*     # Without {} fails
done
```

Here is the output:

```
abcd
abcd%
abcd
abcd

ab
abcd
ab
abcd
abcd%c*
```

Answer (score 7):

#### In Linux shell (`bash`), what does `%` do?

```
for file in *.png.jpg; do
  mv "$file" "${file%.png.jpg}.jpg"
done
```

In this particular case, the `%` is [pattern matching](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSUB2) operator (note it can also be a [modulo](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html#MODULOREF) operator).

---

#### Pattern Matching Operator

> **${var%$Pattern}, ${var%%$Pattern}**
>
> `${var%$Pattern}` Remove from `$var` the shortest part of `$Pattern` that matches the back end of `$var`.
>
> `${var%%$Pattern}` Remove from `$var` the longest part of `$Pattern` that matches the back end of `$var`.
>
> **Example: Pattern matching in parameter substitution**
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # patt-matching.sh
>
> # Pattern matching  using the # ## % %% parameter substitution operators.
>
> var1=abcd12345abc6789
> pattern1=a*c  # * (wild card) matches everything between a - c.
>
> echo
> echo "var1 = $var1"           # abcd12345abc6789
> echo "var1 = ${var1}"         # abcd12345abc6789
>                               # (alternate form)
> echo "Number of characters in ${var1} = ${#var1}"
> echo
>
> echo "pattern1 = $pattern1"   # a*c  (everything between 'a' and 'c')
> echo "--------------"
> echo '${var1#$pattern1}  =' "${var1#$pattern1}"    #         d12345abc6789
> # Shortest possible match, strips out first 3 characters  abcd12345abc6789
> #                                     ^^^^^               |-|
> echo '${var1##$pattern1} =' "${var1##$pattern1}"   #                  6789      
> # Longest possible match, strips out first 12 characters  abcd12345abc6789
> #                                    ^^^^^                |----------|
>
> echo; echo; echo
>
> pattern2=b*9            # everything between 'b' and '9'
> echo "var1 = $var1"     # Still  abcd12345abc6789
> echo
> echo "pattern2 = $pattern2"
> echo "--------------"
> echo '${var1%pattern2}  =' "${var1%$pattern2}"     #     abcd12345a
> # Shortest possible match, strips out last 6 characters  abcd12345abc6789
> #                                     ^^^^                         |----|
> echo '${var1%%pattern2} =' "${var1%%$pattern2}"    #     a
> # Longest possible match, strips out last 12 characters  abcd12345abc6789
> #                                    ^^^^                 |-------------|
>
> # Remember, # and ## work from the left end (beginning) of string,
> #           % and %% work from the right end.
>
> echo
>
> exit 0
> ```

Source [Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSUB2)

---

#### Modulo Operator

> `%`
>
> modulo, or mod (returns the remainder of an integer division
>   operation)
>
> ```
> bash$ expr 5 % 3
> 2
> ```
>
> 5/3 = 1, with remainder 2

Source [Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html#MODULOREF)

Comment: Maybe I got it: this is for things like `.*` and `%` defines it to be non-greedy whereas `%%` makes it greedy? So actually in the rename example it doesn't matter whether to use `%` or `%%` but if it were `mv "$file" "${file%.*png.jpg}.jpg"` (note the *) using %% would rename all files to just `.jpg`, right?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I think that's correct. But I'm no bash expert.

Comment: Saying "Remove ... the shortest part of `$Pattern`" is wrong as the variable `$Pattern` is not defined in the example, only the text "Pattern" is being removed from `$var` when doing `${var%Pattern}` or `${var%%Pattern}`.  Maybe this is just a typo, but it's yet another example of tldp.org being wrong. [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) or [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) are both much better references imho.

Comment: @JohnB Thanks. Both links bookmarked. I've corrected the text in the answer.